# Dismissing an expectation

Tags: word-choice, words, set-phrases

What can be said when I need to dismiss an expectation?

Here are some examples of what I mean by "expectation":

- I ask someone what time it is, then I remembered that I'm actually wearing a watch. The person expects to tell me what time it is but I no longer require help. (Expectation created by me)
- I suspect I do not have enough coins to buy a drink from a coin-only vending machine. I ask someone for change. However I discover that I indeed have enough coins with me. The person still carries an expectation to help me although I no longer require help. (Expectation created by me)
- A waiter offers to refill a glass. He is expected to serve me because of the nature of the job. I do not wish to have a refill. (Expectation not created by me)

I came up with `もう要らない` but I think saying that is unnecessarily direct in conveying "I no longer need (help)".

Comment: For "expectation not created by me", I think I've sometimes heard [お構{かま}いなく](http://eow.alc.co.jp/%E3%81%8A%E6%A7%8B%E3%81%84%E3%81%AA%E3%81%8F/UTF-8/), but I'm not sure whether it's appropriate in that situation or not.

Comment: @cypher That's good too, but it may be too polite if you say it to a waiter. In Japanese society, waiters (or any other kinds of shop clerks) are supposed to be inferior to the customer. If you are a guest, invited to someone's home, then the word is a perfect fit.

Comment: @cypher. You should put it as an answer as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As Sawa said, `やっぱりいいです` works when the expectation is created by you. `いいです` works when the expectation was not created by you.

If you want to be more respectful, you can use `(やはり)結構{けっこう}です`.

There is also a variant `(やっぱり)大丈夫{だいじょうぶ}です` which is heard **a lot**, but some insist that this use of `大丈夫` is wrong or strange.

Just to warn you, `もう要らない` sounds quite rude. `もう` (anymore) could be taken as if you don't need the help anymore because the help wasn't given early enough. `要らない` sounds a bit like "I don't need and I don't want".

The いい/結構 variants are really the best, similar to English "I'm fine, thanks".

Comment: Would もういいです be rude too?

Comment: I would avoid もう altogether, as it sounds like the help was given too late. やっぱり sounds like the *speaker* changed her/his mind and therefore has no accusatory nuance.

Answer (score 6):

In your "expectation created by me" cases, the normal way to say it is:

> やっぱり、いいです。
>   'After all, I'm okay (without your help)'.

In your "expectation not created by me" case, the normal way is:

> けっこうです。
>   'No thank you.'

But depending on intonation, `けっこうです` may be heard as offensive, just as the English "no thanks" is. So be careful. If you say it gently, it suffices.