# Correct phrase for "I'm just browsing" in a store

Tags: translation, word-choice, expressions

I've been trying to figure out what the correct translation is of the phrase "I'm just browsing", in a context such as when one is looking at goods in a store (e.g. if you're walking around the shop and employee asks if you need help).

This should be straightforward, but my dictionary gives many possible translations for "browsing" (e.g. 素見{すけん}、冷{ひ}やかし、閲覧{えつらん}, etc.)  and I'm not sure which would be appropriate here. What's the most appropriate translation of this phrase in the given context?

Comment: related: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/5056/how-to-shoo-away-a-sales-clerk

Comment: For this question, it says [1k views] -- this must be a bug ? or lots of F5 ? ___________ Now it says [2k views]  ! ! w w w w w w w

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The most common phrase would be:

> 見てるだけです。(Literally: "I'm just looking.")

I think you could also reply like this:

> 店員：何かお探しですか？(Are you looking for anything in particular?) 　　
>   客：いえ、だいじょうぶです。(No, I'm okay.)

Comment: Only if you are talking to a brilliant but obnoxious doctor with a cane and a Vicodin addiction.

Comment: @Kevin I get the reference, but I'm not sure how it applies.

Comment: @Ouroborus "いいえ, だいじょうぶです" is "No, I'm okay".  He wrote いえ, だいじょうぶです which means "House, I'm okay"

Comment: @Kevin As you can see in [this dictionary](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/9811/meaning/m0u/%E3%81%84%E3%81%88/) and [this dictionary](http://www.romajidesu.com/dictionary/meaning-of-%E3%81%84%E3%81%88.html), you can say いえ, いや, as well as いいえ to mean "No". (Here I chose いえ because it sounds a bit softer than いいえ to me)

Comment: people knows the context. They won't determined it as "house". Also, it is spoken word, grammar mistake can be tolerated. And which foreigner can actually distinguish long vowels? I know I can't.

Comment: Those いえs have different intonation from each other, however いえ for "no" has variations and can overlap the other one.

Comment: I would still argue that you should write it correctly, especially on a site where people come to learn Japanese

Comment: @Kevin いえ is not incorrect. It's in dictionaries. It's widely used both in fiction and in real life. Japanese learners learn it in [JLPT N3 grammar](http://www.tanos.co.uk/jlpt/skills/vocab/sentences/?vocabid=85682). You wouldn't be able to communicate with Japanese people properly if you interpreted sentences with 「いえ、～～」 as "House, blah blah..." If you're interested to know the difference in usage and nuance between いえ and いいえ, you can post a new question.

Comment: @chocolate My instructors in language school considered it incorrect.  Also,  the very page you linked to consistently writes いいえ as in : "いいえ、ちょっと見ているだけです。 No, thank you. I'm just looking."

Comment: @Kevin But you can see 「いえ、結構です」, which is close in meaning to 「いえ、大丈夫です」, there, right? Are your instructors native speakers of Japanese? 「いえ、大丈夫です」 is a common phrase that we Japanese use in daily life. No native speaker would consider 「いえ、～～」 as incorrect. You can see sentences 「いえ、大丈夫です」 and 「いえ、音がおかしいんです。」  in [this real JLPT N2 exam](http://members.iinet.net.au/~richardlam/JLPT%20Level%201-4%201991-2005%20Exam%20Papers/1992-2.htm).

Comment: @Kevin Just adding another voice to say いえ used like this is perfectly fine, very common and not incorrect...

Comment: @chocolate yes, all four of my instructors were native Japanese

Comment: @Kevin I also took 1 year of Japanese in Kyoto. All of my teachers were natives and they always taught natural and casual expressions such as いえ, omitting the topic particle, or slang like わからん (they even taught Kansai-ben). Some of these casual expressions even show up in the JLPT, so you're required to understand them.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I would and have used:

> ただ見ているだけです

"Just looking/browsing."